# Combo box display only blank list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extjs, combobox, ext.net

I am using Ext.net 3.0. I have a combo box and created store in it to get multiple values from server side. It's getting 5 value from server side, but it display only blank list.

[image]

Coding for combo box..............

```
   <ext:ComboBox runat="server" ListWidth="350" ID="Branches" FieldLabel="Branch" DisplayField="Name" ValueField="Number" AllowBlank="false">
                        <Store>
                            <ext:Store runat="server">
                                <Reader>
                                    <ext:JsonReader IDProperty="Number">
                                        <Fields>
                                            <ext:RecordField Name="Number"></ext:RecordField>
                                            <ext:RecordField Name="Name"></ext:RecordField>
                                        </Fields>
                                    </ext:JsonReader>
                                </Reader>
                            </ext:Store>
                        </Store>
</ext:ComboBox>
```

Server side coding.......

```
  var branchList = from b in Branches select new { Number = b.Number, Name =   b.Name };

  List<object> listBranchToAdd = new List<object>();
  foreach (var a in branchList)
   {
     listBranchToAdd.Add(a);
   }

  Branches.Store.Primary.DataSource = listBranchToAdd;
  Branches.Store.Primary.DataBind();
```

My Research  -

1. Someone said that, don't add a combo in store directly, create a store   separately by given store id and then use store id in combo, but it doesn't work.
2. var branchList returning value.. I have checked it. When i use
   cmbBranches.setValue(listBranchToAdd[0]); then it display value in Fiddler. but     doesn't display in combo box properly.

3.Just give a storeId in store and use in server side for binding data in store        instead of binding in combobox. I have tried it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure your html is update after assign `DataSource` to `combobox`.

Comment: Hi Anant, Html is being updated. I have tried by adding static value in combo box.

Comment: So if u add static value then your combobox is works ?

Comment: Yes, it display value but not in correct format. I just added temporary to check html is updating or not.

Comment: check this link its might be helpful to you...http://examples.ext.net/#/Form/ComboBox/Ajax_Linked_Combos/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81610/discussion-between-puneet-chawla-and-anant-dabhi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got a solution of this question. I didn't properly understand the actual logic why it's working but it works proper.

Previous Code - It was not working

```
var branchList = from b in Branches select new { Number = b.Number, Name =   b.Name };

  List<object> listBranchToAdd = new List<object>();
  foreach (var a in branchList)
   {
     listBranchToAdd.Add(a);
   }

  Branches.Store.Primary.DataSource = listBranchToAdd;
  Branches.Store.Primary.DataBind();
```

New Code - It is working

```
var branchList = from b in Branches select b;

      List<Branch> listBranchToAdd = new List<Branch>();
      foreach (var a in branchList)
       {
         listBranchToAdd.Add(a);
       }

      Branches.Store.Primary.DataSource = listBranchToAdd;
      Branches.Store.Primary.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this example

```
<ext:ComboBox runat="server" ID="cmb" EmptyText="select.." ForceSelection="true" AllowBlank="false"
Editable="false" Icon="BulletTick" Flex="1" ValueField="Id" DisplayField="Name" FieldLabel="Name">
        <Store>
         <ext:Store ID="strcmb" runat="server">
              <Model>
                  <ext:Model ID="Model4" runat="server">
                     <Fields>
                      <ext:ModelField Name="Number" />
                      <ext:ModelField Name="Name" />
                     </Fields>
                  </ext:Model>
              </Model>
         </ext:Store>
    </Store>
</ext:ComboBox>
```

and server side

```
 strcmb.DataSource = _bll.Get();
 strcmb.DataBind();
```

in yor case you dont need to  `<Reader><ext:JsonReader...>` this part if dont make a web service request

**update**

```
    var branchList = from b in Branches select new MyClass { Number = b.Number, Name =   b.Name };

strcmb.DataSource = branchList.ToList();
  strcmb.DataBind();
        MyClass{
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public int Number {get ;set;}
        }
```

Comment: Hi Sakir, I tried it but still it display blank list in combo.

Comment: did u change those <ext:ModelField Name="Id" />
                      <ext:ModelField Name="Name" /> according to your values(Name,Number)

Comment: Yes, I changed. I think, it's mistake of server side, it also doesn't display value in Fiddler. I have all value in this variable "listBranchToAdd" (check in my question). When i directly set value in combo, it display (not in correct format). But i can't do this. I want to bind all value in onetime in combo.